# Distinct between request by a content type

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create an API which can handle multiple post request on the same endpoint. I'd like to distinct between these requests by a content type.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json;data-model=1")
    public String post1(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> body) {
        return "Post1";
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json;data-model=2")
    public String post2(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> body) {
        return "Post2";
    }
}
```

With this code, I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/': {public java.lang.String com.example.demo.TestController.post1(java.util.HashMap,java.lang.String), public java.lang.String com.example.demo.TestController.post2(java.util.HashMap,java.lang.String)}
```

I've seen it's possible to distinct by different query params. Is it also somehow possible for content type? Or am I forced into a large `switch..case`?

> Why would I even want to do so?

I'm testing this approach:
https://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-api-on-cqrs/

Comment: Have you tested it? I suggest you do.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I've updated my question with an error, forget about that before

Comment: apparently the part after the `;` isn't taken into account, as differentiating on content-type just works. (Everything in a `@*Mapping` is used for mapping, the name of the annotation is a bit of a give-away). You could register a improvement request. Really using a special content-type (as done article you linked to) will work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that's right! I've changed content to `application/vnd.data-model1+json` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Solution, thanks to M.Deinum:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/vnd.data-model1+json")
    public String post1(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> body) {
        return "Post1";
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/vnd.data-model2+json")
    public String post2(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> body) {
        return "Post2";
    }
}
```